# Is possible integrate Nodejs with Cakephp?

Tags: node.js, cakephp

I want to monitor in real time the data that users enter in `comments` table. 
I have an Apache server running, and suppose that has a node server on port 1337.

**How would I do that every time someone save new data, eg return me the total number of table rows in `comment` and show it in a `view`?**

Maybe way is to make the `$this->Comment->save($this->request->data);` using a different port using [Httpsockect](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/httpsocket.html)?

Comment: i don't think nodejs would be a nice solution for your task, its a bit too much to install nodejs and just use websocket for comments. longpolling fits nicer for this kind of task you can achieve this with php without too much of effort.

Comment: Thanks, what i search for achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You have multiple ways of solving this, let me give you my ideas

You can simply use long-polling and don't use Node.js at all. It's a suitable solution if there won't be too much traffic there, otherwise you will have a bad time.

You can use websockets and don't use Node.js at all. [Here you have a basic guide about websockets and PHP](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket). Although, I am almost sure you won't be able to create "rooms", that is, sending notifications for specific comments.

You can also use [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/). This is a more sophisticated library to handle websockets and it supports rooms.

Lastly, if you want to full dive in with Node.js and CakePHP, I would suggest start by [watching this talk given on Cakefest 2012](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bDsisO9eiwc) which exactly describe your scenario.

After you have watched that, you might want to learn a little about [Socket.io](http://socket.io/). This is a more complex solution, but it's what I have used when integrating CakePHP and Node.js to create real time applications.

The strategy here is to have the users join a [room](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms) when they visit /article/view/123, let's say the room name is the articleID, then socket.io will be listening for events happening in this room.

You will have a Cakephp method that handles the save. Then, when user submits the form you don't call directly the Cake action, you have socket.io to dispatch an event, then in your event you pass the data to the server (Node.js) and nodejs will call your cakephp function that saves the data. When Nodejs receives confirmation from CakePHP then you broadcast an event (using socket.io), this event will let know all users connected to that room that a comment has been made.

Comment: Thaaaanksss!!! Can you post a little example of the final of your answer? calling socket.io and sockect.io calling my function?

Comment: I will, probably in a blog post as there is a lot of code involved.

Comment: 1 year later: http://www.slideshare.net/gmansilla1/behind-the-scenes-of-realtime-notifications

Comment: @GuillemoMansilla Thank you so much for those slides. This needs more exposure somehow :D

Answer (score 1):

You have basically the choice between Websockets and long polling.

- Websockets (with [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) and [Autobahn.js](http://autobahn.ws/js/))
- Long Polling Using [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

Decide which technology you want to use and start implementing your use case. Consider that Websockets are more or less new. Depending on your requirements you might not be able to use Websockets because you might have to support crappy browsers. [See this page](http://caniuse.com/websockets).

Comment: Ratchet seems to support IE8+