# Web sockets to grab live data from my server

Tags: php, mysql, websocket

I'm wanting to push real time data to my website via web sockets. The data is basically just text saying "Artist - Title", it is generated via my Windows server that is streaming live constantly.

Can anybody point me in the right direction (i.e a manual/knowledge site) where I can read up on what will be required? Right now I have a PHP script that is pulling data from the MySQL database on my server, that then drops it onto my site as described above (Artist - Title) - obviously this doesn't accomplish what I want as it requires people to refresh the site every time they want to see what's currently being streamed, what I want is for it to just appear the second it starts playing on my server.

I've tried researching into web sockets with no prevail to what I want to accomplish. If anybody has the knowledge as to what I'm missing to make this work I would be most appreciative of your answer.

Comment: I answered a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22383873/1132836. I also posted the link to the slides I used during my presentation, you will also find the link to my repo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider running a Node.js server with socket.io. See socket.io [chat app tutorial](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/) and it should become clear.

Basically you need JavaScript on your page to open the socket and respond to messages.